# QtDesigner ui and Javascript

Tags: qt

I have searched for an example of using the QtDesigner UI file with Javascript but was unable to find one. Is this possible? Alternatively is it possible with minimalist cpp? This is for a desktop application. I would like to use Javascript for the interactive side of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what you mean by "I would like to use Javascript for the interactive side of the application".

If you have a look at [QML](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdeclarativeintroduction.html) which is Qt's Javascript based declarative language for UI development, you can indeed [use Javascript](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdeclarativejavascript.html) to add some functionality to the application.

I am not 100% sure whether or not this can be used via QtDesigner.

Comment: I want to use Javascript with the QtDesigner ui file rather than using QML, and I don't want to use cpp, or at the most very minimally. In this way, the screen can be built using drag and drop similar to IB, etc. etc.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge this is not possible. But perhaps someone else will prove me wrong.